# What does t() do in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to understand what `t()` or  `t (n, a)` does in the following example

```
     SELECT numbers, animals, n, a
        FROM (
          VALUES
            (ARRAY[2, 5], ARRAY['dog', 'cat', 'bird']),
            (ARRAY[7, 8, 9], ARRAY['cow', 'pig'])
        ) AS x (numbers, animals)
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers, animals) AS t (n, a);
```

Result:

```
  numbers  |     animals      |  n   |  a
-----------+------------------+------+------
 [2, 5]    | [dog, cat, bird] |    2 | dog
 [2, 5]    | [dog, cat, bird] |    5 | cat
 [2, 5]    | [dog, cat, bird] | NULL | bird
 [7, 8, 9] | [cow, pig]       |    7 | cow
 [7, 8, 9] | [cow, pig]       |    8 | pig
 [7, 8, 9] | [cow, pig]       |    9 | NULL
(6 rows)
```

[Source](https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/141t/sql/select.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)

> ```
> UNNEST( array_expression [, ... ] ) [WITH ORDINALITY] [[AS] table_alias [(column_alias [, ... ])]]
> ```
>
> If no table_alias is specified, the function name is used as the table name; in the case of a ROWS FROM() construct, the first function's name is used.
>
> **If column aliases are not supplied, then for a function returning a base data type, the column name is also the same as the function name.** For a function returning a composite type, the result columns get the names of the individual attributes of the type.

```
SELECT numbers, animals, t.*
    FROM (
      VALUES
        (ARRAY[2, 5], ARRAY['dog', 'cat', 'bird']),
        (ARRAY[7, 8, 9], ARRAY['cow', 'pig'])
    ) AS x (numbers, animals)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers, animals) AS t
                                  --AS t(n,a)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e41dd9d2133b1e8cacaa2566368a7623)**

Answer (score 1):

`t(k, v)` is what you get when unpacking a nested structure, in this case the arrays. `t` is the alias of the "table" or unpacked field. `k` would be the first value and `v` is the second value.

https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/FTrSJJOjpjqIZ6ue5YuiCQ